# About the communicating classes

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

[image]

I think there is a mistake in the answer (from the book) of this problem.

The answer is:

{0},d=1

{1},d=0

{2,3,4,5}, d=1

I think state 1 must be with the states {2,3,4,5} and therefore with d=1.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Notice that, the states $\{2,3,4,5\}$ form a closed communicating class. State 1 is not communicating with any of the states in the class $\{2,3,4,5\}$. State 1 itself forms a class that is non-closed. It is non-closed because there is an escape from state 1 to state 2. When one the chain moves from state 1 to state 2, it will never visit state 1.

### [image]

---

Comment: Oh I see, what a clear explanation thanks